# Should I use Stream.Flush before Stream.CopyTo?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, memorystream

I have MemoryStream that I'm filling up with some data using StreamWriter.
At the end I want to dump it to different stream (not always file).

Should I call Stream.Flush before using Steram.CopyTo method?

Comment: What is a reason of the question? Can you elaborate a problem that you try to resolve? If this is a curiosity question then no, you don't have to flush current data before using CopyTo for either stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never need to call `Flush` on a memory stream, because the operation does nothing. If you look at the source, the implementation is empty. You do need to rewind the stream after writing.

However, you need to flush the `StreamWriter`, to make sure that all the data is pushed into the memory stream before you start copying it.

You can use this pattern with `StreamWriter` writing to memory stream to avoid explicit flushing:

```
MemoryStream memStream = ...
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(memStream)) {
    ... // Do the writing
}
memStream.Position = 0; // Rewind
// At this point `memStream` has all data pushed into it,
// and is positioned at zero, so it's ready to be copied.
```

Comment: Thank you. Where are you checking source code of MemoryStream.Flush()?

Comment: @Hooch I found reflected source online [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/MemoryStream@cs/1305376/MemoryStream@cs). Scroll down or search to see the code (top 250+ lines are comments, which are lost in reflected sources).

Comment: Thanks. That will come in handy in situations like this one.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I call Stream.Flush before using Stream.CopyTo method?

No, there isn't a need to call `Flush`. But, you will need to reset the `Position` to 0 on the `MemoryStream`.

The `CopyTo` docs say:

> Copying begins at the **current position** in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.